# MVC action method not getting hit

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have Layout page where my left navigation bar is defined. I want to load the sub options for a menu item in the left navigation bar. I have added an ajax click event for the top menu item . But it always hit the default method defined in the RouteMap, not the action method which i have written to load the partial view.

My Routeconfig.cs file. I have also other maps defined this file. But this is the method which is getting hit.

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { 
               controller = "Client", 
               action = "Index", 
               id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The menu item in my _Layout Page

```
 <li>
    <a href="#" id="recentlist">Recent list</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
               <a href="#" class="back">Main Menu</a>
            </li>
            <div id="recentClients"></div>  
       </ul>
 </li>
```

This is my javascript defined in the _Layout page.

```
$('#recentlist').click(function () {           
        $.ajax({
            Url: "@Url.Action("RecentList", "Navigation")",             
            success: function (r) {
                $('#recentClients').html(r);
            }
        });
    });
```

But it never hits the RecentList method in my NavigationController. It was always goes to the default method defined in the RouteConfig.cs

Also this is my controller code.

```
public ActionResult RecentList()
    {
        var clientModel = new ClientModel();
        var recentlList = clientModel.GetRecentList();
        return PartialView("_RecentlList", recentlList );
    }
```

Comment: All you have shown is a method named `RecentlyUsedList` not `RecentList` - is that a typo (along with the incorrect `id` attribute)?

Comment: The ajax option should also be `url: ...`, not `Url: ...` (lower case)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - ahh!! Thats the problem. I didnt realize the U was on caps. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Hard to be 100% sure, but you're `ActionResult` is named `RecentlyUsedList` while your're trying to hit a endpoint called `RecentList` in the `NavigationController`.

So it should be:

```
@Url.Action("RecentlyUsedList", "Navigation");
```

And the controller needs to be named `NavigationController`.